# Limit/Number of html file (containing text) within an epub file

Tags: android, epublib

I'm using the following method from epublib to retrieve the content:

is = book.getSpine().getSpineReferences().get(number).getResource().getInputStream();

How do I know when number has reached the last file and is out of range?

Answer (score 0):

I found: book.getContents().size()